# format image data to predict a number in the image for MNIST data model

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm having problems in trying Keras with MNIST. I have a saved model that has more than 99% accuracy but when I use it to predict some images it always predics a 1. I think it's due to me reshaping the image data input in the wrong way in the test.py file.

I got the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28)
```

Or if I try a random reshape (1, 1, 28, 28) I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (None, 28, 28, 1) but got array with shape (1, 1, 28, 28)
```

So I tried adding the following in my image_to_data function:

```
image_data = image_data.reshape((1, 28, 28, 1))
```

Now the code runs but always predicts the same values. How can I reshape the image data 28 x 28 pixels to that it fits the first layer in the model in the correct way for predicting the class of one image?

train.py

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 20

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
             activation='relu',
             input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
      batch_size=batch_size,
      epochs=epochs,
      verbose=1,
      validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

# serialize model to YAML
model_yaml = model.to_yaml()
with open("model-new.yaml", "w") as yaml_file:
yaml_file.write(model_yaml)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("model-new.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

test.py

```
from PIL import Image
from keras.models import model_from_yaml
import numpy as np

def load_model():
    # load YAML and create model
    yaml_file = open('model.yaml', 'r')
    model_yaml = yaml_file.read()
    yaml_file.close()
    model = model_from_yaml(model_yaml)
    # load weights into new model
    model.load_weights("model.h5")
    print("Loaded model from disk")
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

def image_to_data(image):
    image_data = np.array(image) / 255
    image_data = image_data.reshape((1, 28, 28, 1))
    return image_data

def predict(model, image):
    data = image_to_data(image)
    prediction = model.predict_classes(data)
    return prediction

def predict_image(model, filename):
    image = Image.open(filename)
    data = image_to_data(image)
    prediction = predict(model, data)
    return prediction

model = load_model()
print(predict_image(model, '3.png'))
print(predict_image(model, '6.png'))
print(predict_image(model, '8.png'))
```

Comment: First I would try to reduce the amount of epochs while training the model, the model could be already overfitting (99% accuracy). To evaluate this, you could implement a cross validation test with keras very easily. This allows you to get a more realistic idea of the accuracy as you fluently can compare the test accuracy (test with training pictures) with the cross validation accuracy (test with pictures the model has never seen before) over the whole course of the training process.

Comment: I have a separate test set from the mnist data (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data(), but maybe I should check again so that module does not have that data in the training set as well, I assumed that it would not since it would not make sense to have it in both places.

Comment: You could also do something like np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)/255. That converted my (256, 256, 3) images to (1, 256, 256, 3).

Answer (score 1):

Possible problems:

- (not your case) MNIST data is normalized between 0 and 1, and your image may be from 0 to 255 as usual (compare `image_data.max()` with `x_train.max()`)
- MNIST data may have black and white colors inverted in relation to your images. After assuring everything is normalized between 0 and 1, use a tool to plot an image from `x_train` and to plot `image_data`. See if the colors are inverted. Or try predicing with `image_data = 1 - image_data`.
- Depending on the way you're loading your images, you may have it transposed. After checking the two previous items, you may try to `image_data = numpy.swapaxes(image_data,1,2)`
- Overfitting, as mentioned by @hi_im_vinzent. If all the three previous items are ok, try predicting with the training images to see if the model is doing it right.
- If none of the previous worked, then you've probably got a problem when saving/loading the model.

Comment: Thanks! Those where good points as well as the ones @hl_im_vinzent had. I'll really try to check for color inverted/rotated images. it's just that I also think that the image_data.reshape((1, 28, 28, 1)) command really might have gone wrong, I'm not sure in what how that magic reshaping happens. I'm to new to numpy to understand how to use it. How to safely reshape a 2d image array into (1, 28, 28, 1) (I can't even vizualize in my head right now how that new shape looks, to many dimensions)?

Comment: As you said I needed to invert the images, that is done now. I also extracted two of the images from the MNIST test set to try with as well. Neither of this gives anything else than 1 as predictions regardless of image. If it was overfitting at least the MNIST images should have given the correct predictions. I'll investigate further.

Comment: Numpy arrays are a straight sequence of elements grouped by dimensions. When you reshape, you just change the grouping, without any kind of reordering. It's different from transpose,swapaxes,rollaxis, etc., where the data is actually reordered to reflect a change. Any kind of reshape that has (any number of ones, 28, any number of ones, 28, any number of ones) will work without any real change to the data. (Of course keras will only accept those in the form (batch, 28,28, channels).